# javascript array of objects with most basic form

Tags: reactjs

Need to store and access values on an array in react. So far I found solutions that uses filters or does not fit my requirements.

Just need to push a string value with string key, and retrieve it with same key. How to do it?

Code:

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useRef } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const Presence = useRef({});

  function objTest() {
    Presence.current.length = 0;
    const uid = "UID1"; //Date.now().toString();

    //let obj = { [uid]:{ presence: "Busy"} };
    let obj = { [uid]: "Busy" };

    Presence.current.push(obj);

    console.log(Presence.current, " , ", Presence.current[uid]);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>

      {objTest()}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: you mentioned array, but your code is using object. do u want object or array? You cannot access "busy" if you are using Presence.current[uid].

Comment: I'm not sure which is possible for this need, my priority is object.

Answer (score 1):

> Just need to push a string value with string key, and retrieve it with same key

All modern browsers support [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), which does exactly what you want:

```
const Presence = useRef(new Map());
```

You can use it like:

```
Presence.current.set(key, value)
Presence.current.has(key)
Presence.current.get(key)
```

---

Old way would be use an object literal like you have `const Presence = useRef({});`  and do use [`Property_accessors#bracket_notation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#bracket_notation)  like `Presence.current[uid] = "Busy"` to add dynamic keys. Object literals don't have a `length` or `size` property and are harder to enumerate so I don't recommend it unless you need to support IE

Comment: Thank you for your response. Is there any other way without map?

Comment: Another way is to use an object literal like you have  `const Presence = useRef({});
` and do `Presence.current[uid] = "Busy"`. Object literals don't have a `length` or `size` property and are harder to enumerate so I don't recommend it unless you need to support IE

Comment: The code works fine on codesandBox, but on my project on VSCode it is giving me an error - `TypeError: Presence.current.set is not a function` . Will you please give me any hint on solving this?

Comment: @Rifat try `console.log(Presence.current)` and see if it's still a map. Maybe your actual cod is setting it to `null` or something at some point

Comment: Its resolved. One more thing that I need a way to update UI if the map value is changed. So I set another variable with useState `const presenceCondition = useRef(new Map()); const [Presence, setPresence] = useState(new Map());               presenceCondition.current.set(uid, presenceConditionVariable);
              setPresence(presenceCondition.current);
` and updating and using its value, it initially shows but I'm not getting success on updating UI. Will you please help me to update UI?

Comment: @Rifat "I need a way to update UI if the map value is changed" - if this is the case I think the second method will object literal would be better option for you. Why do you need a ref and a state? maybe you just need a state? and when state changes react does a re-render...

Answer (score 1):

Why not use state?

```
const Component = () => {

 const [ state, setState ] = useState({});
 const [ arrayState, setArrayState ] = useState([])
 const [ savedUid, setSavedUid ] = useState('') //need to save your UID too

 function objTest() {
    
        const uid = "UID1"; //Date.now().toString();
        setState({ [uid]: 'Busy'}) // object
        setArrayState(prev => [...prev, { [uid]: 'Busy' }] ) //array of objects
        setSavedUid(uid) //save your uid
 }
 console.log('Object', state[savedUid])
 console.log('Array of Objects', arrayState[0][savedUid])

 return <button onClick={objTest}>Click Me</button>
```

}

Comment: any way to retrieve value from arrayState without index or search ? `arrayState[0][savedUid]`?